# Unable to get values from radio form fields using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to make E-commerce website for practice and wanted to get values from Radio form field wether the buyer wants to pay the cash on delivery or want to make payment using PayPal. I want to get the form field value so that, if its COD, I just show "Order placed" to user but if its paypal, I redirect to Payment gateway.

Below is my Code

```
<div class="form-check">
    <input type="radio" name="paymentmode" id="cod" class="form-check-input" value="cod">
    <label for="cod">Cash on Delivery</label>   
    <input type="radio" name="paymentmode" id="paypal" class="form-check-input" value="paypal">
    <label for="paypal">PayPal</label>
</div>
```

And the JS code is below

```
<script>
    var radio = $("input[name='paymentmode']:checked").val();
    var button = $('.theButton');

    button.click(function() {
        alert(radio);
    });
</script>
```

Whenever I click the button, the alert shows up but it says "undefined" instead of the value from the radio fields. Please help me

EDIT: I TRIED TO FETCH SOME OTHER VALUE LIKE NAME OR ADDRESS AND THE ALERT BOX JUST RETURNS NOTHING, ITS AN EMPTY ALERT BOX

Comment: You're retrieving the value on pageload, before the input has been populated

Comment: How do I solve this?

Comment: By retrieving the value in the listener instead of on pageload, since it's empty on pageload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code isn't working because you have set the value first in a variable and whenever the radio button value changes it doesn't affect that variable that's why your code didn't work as expected.

Try below working code -

```js
$('.theButton').click(function() {
  console.log($("input[name=paymentmode]:checked").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-check">
  <input type="radio" name="paymentmode" id="cod" class="form-check-input" value="cod">
  <label for="cod">Cash on Delivery</label>
  <input type="radio" name="paymentmode" id="paypal" class="form-check-input" value="paypal">
  <label for="paypal">PayPal</label>
  <button class='theButton'>Click It!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: My Pleasure :) @Steal1702

Answer (score 0):

"radio" going to get data When you click the button.

```
<script>
var radio;
var button = $('.theButton');

    button.click(function() {
        radio = $("input[name='paymentmode']:checked").val();
        alert(radio);
        });
</script>
```